# Dagger2 + Kotlin, Injection not working

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

Unfortunately, Dagger2 is not creating the instance of my objects to be injected.

- Dagger: 2.0.2
- Kotlin: 1.0.1-2

Source code? [Here](https://github.com/ppamorim/Amazing-MVP-Kotlin/blob/master/amazingmvp-kotlin/src/main/java/com/amazingmvpkotlin/ui/activity/HomeActivity.kt#L39)

Component:

```
@ActivityScope @Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
    modules = { HomeModule.class })
public interface HomeComponent {
  void inject(HomeActivity homeActivity);
  HomePresenter homePresenter();
}
```

Module:

```
@Module public class HomeModule {
  @Provides @ActivityScope HomePresenter provideHomePresenter(
      HomePresenterImpl presenter) {
    return presenter;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update the version of Dagger to `2.2`.